# QT5 QML Charts: how to label only subset of points

Tags: charts, qml, qt5

By default, in QML Charts LineSeries all the points are labelled. I need to label only specific points, how to achieve this ?

Here is my qml file (part of big project). I have set corresponding properties for LineSeries to show point labels, but I need only couple of labels displayed instead of complete set of points. Is there a way in Qml to control this ?

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtCharts 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import aa.ui.backend 1.0

Item {
property DSPBackend backend: analyzer.dsp

property alias titleV: chartV.title
property alias seriesV: lineSeriesV
property alias titleI: chartI.title
property alias seriesI: lineSeriesI

GridLayout {
    id: gridSpectrum
    anchors.fill: parent
    columns: 2
    rows: 1
    columnSpacing: 0
    flow: GridLayout.LeftToRight

    ChartView {
        id: chartV
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        /*title: "Spectrum (V-channel)"
        titleFont.pixelSize: 10*/
        theme: ChartView.ChartThemeBlueCerulean
        antialiasing: false
        legend.visible: false
        legend.font.pointSize: 10
        margins.top: 2
        margins.left: 2
        margins.right: 2
        margins.bottom: 4

        ValueAxis {
            id: axisXV
            titleFont.pointSize: 7
            labelsFont.pointSize: 7
        }

        ValueAxis {
            id: axisYV
            titleFont.pointSize: 7
            labelsFont.pointSize: 7
        }

        LineSeries {
            id: lineSeriesV
            axisX: axisXV
            axisY: axisYV
            color: "#66cc00"
            name: "V-channel"
            pointLabelsFormat: "(@xPoint Hz, @yPoint dB)"
            pointLabelsVisible: true
            width: 3
            useOpenGL: false
        }
    }

    ChartView {
        id: chartI
        /*title: "Spectrum (I-channel)"
        titleFont.pixelSize: 10*/
        antialiasing: true
        theme: ChartView.ChartThemeBlueCerulean
        legend.visible: false
        legend.font.pointSize: 10
        margins.top: 2
        margins.left: 2
        margins.right: 2
        margins.bottom: 4
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true

        ValueAxis {
            id: axisXI
            titleFont.pointSize: 7
            labelsFont.pointSize: 7
        }

        ValueAxis {
            id: axisYI
            titleFont.pointSize: 7
            labelsFont.pointSize: 7
        }

        LineSeries {
            id: lineSeriesI
            axisX: axisXI
            axisY: axisYI
            color: "#0099ff"
            name: "I-channel"
            pointLabelsFormat: "(@xPoint Hz, @yPoint dB)"
            pointLabelsVisible: true
            width: 3
            useOpenGL: false
        }

    }

}

Timer {
    id: timerSpectrum
    interval: 500
    running: true
    repeat: true
    onTriggered: {
        backend.update_spectrum(seriesV, seriesI);
    }
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    backend.setup_spectrum(axisXV, axisYV, axisXI, axisYI)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a bool property or a function that returns a bool. Then evaluate it in the pointLabelsFormat property.

```
pointLabelsFormat: myBool? "(@xPoint Hz, @yPoint dB)" : ""
```

If the boolean is false it sets the point's label to an empty string.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how do I know which point I am evaluating?
 Unless xPoint and yPoint are real values...

Comment: All the points in your LineSeries will be evaluated, but only those who match your criterion will display the label ***"(@xPoint Hz, @yPoint dB)"***

When you said: "I need only couple of labels displayed instead of complete set of points" what is the criterion to decide which points are to be displayed and which are not??

Comment: ok, I got your idea, i.e. I need to apply  my algorithm and choose what points to display

Comment: Exactly :) Good luck, friend.

Comment: No, unfortunately it is not going to work.. pointLabelsFormat is just a string field/property. The value we pass there is just a format string. I need a callback where every point is evaluated...

Comment: Let's say you only want to display the points whose index is an odd number, then you'd set a condition like:

Comment: `pointLabelsFormat: (index % 2 === 1) ? "(@xPoint Hz, @yPoint dB)" : ""`

Comment: QML allows you to pass one string or the other depending on a condition. So, pointLabelsFormat is only receiving one string.

Comment: You think that pointLabelsFormat is evaluated for every point, right? But it is not... it is a constant string , evaluated once. What is "index" variable in your example ?

Comment: Ohhh got it... I thought it would be evaluated for every point and that you could access the point's index in the list, the way it's done with data models.

Comment: I need to review source code and look if there is an easy way to provide a callback from c++ code... That might be a solution.